# Replace value from previous row in same column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, replace

I have a column in dataframe like this

```
test_data = pd.DataFrame({'Category':['Finance - Loan','1','2','3','4','Finance - Loan - Car','1','2', 'Car - Loan','1', '2', '3']})
```

How do i replace the number with the value before. The data type is string. Is there anyone can help?

Comment: can you provide your expected output?

Comment: test_data = pd.DataFrame({'Category':['Finance - Loan','Finance - Loan','Finance - Loan','Finance - Loan','Finance - Loan','Finance - Loan - Car','Finance - Loan - Car','Finance - Loan - Car', 'Car - Loan','Car - Loan', 'Car - Loan', 'Car - Loan']})

Comment: @Ramesh it's just like copy the text and paste to number and next text again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the numeric strings with NaN and use `fillna()` method

```
col = df['Category']
col[col.str.isnumeric()] = None
col = col.fillna(method='ffill')
df['Category'] = col
```

Result

```
    Category
0   Finance - Loan
1   Finance - Loan
2   Finance - Loan
3   Finance - Loan
4   Finance - Loan
5   Finance - Loan - Car
6   Finance - Loan - Car
7   Finance - Loan - Car
8   Car - Loan
9   Car - Loan
10  Car - Loan
11  Car - Loan
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**  bui answer is better.

```
import pandas as pd

test_data = pd.DataFrame(
{'Category': ['Finance - Loan', '1', '2', '3', '4', 'Finance - Loan - Car', '1', '2', 'Car - Loan', '1', '2', '3']})
lst = test_data['Category'].tolist()
test = []
for i in lst:
    if not i.isdigit():
        test.append(i)
    if i.isdigit():
        test.append(test[-1])
test_data['Category'] = test
print(test_data)
```

Comment: but it on dataframe, how i put back again on same column in dataframe?

Comment: i have updated the code. you can replace the contents of list to the columns by calling it's column name.